# Creating a search bar in php and html

Tags: php, uisearchbar

I want to create a search bar in a php file using only html, css and java script. While even the most simple codes work in an html file they do not work in an php file. The goal here is that a search bar can search through an ul list while the list only shows results similar to what is typed into the search bar. Kinda like the common file systems search bar actually. When I put my code in an html file it works perfectly however the very same code doesnt react to the input in the search bar when it is used in an php file.

I tried making the code as simple as possible but it still doesnt work as a php file. I dont believe there is something wrong with the html code since it works as an html file but does someone know a way to use it in a php file correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
form {
        background-color: #990000;
        width: 300px;
        height: 44px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        align-items:center;
      }

      input {
        all: unset;
        font: 18px system-ui;
        color: #fff;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 6px 10px;
      }

      ::placeholder {
        color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.7; 
      }

      svg {
        color: #fff;
        fill: currentColor;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      button {
        all: unset;
        cursor: pointer;
        width:44px;
        height:44px;
      }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h2>Search</h2>
<form role="search" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search..." title="Type in a name">
    <button>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><path class="path1" d="M848.471 928l-263.059-263.059c-48.941 36.706-110.118 55.059-177.412 55.059-171.294 0-312-140.706-312-312s140.706-312 312-312c171.294 0 312 140.706 312 312 0 67.294-24.471 128.471-55.059 177.412l263.059 263.059-79.529 79.529zM189.623 408.078c0 121.364 97.091 218.455 218.455 218.455s218.455-97.091 218.455-218.455c0-121.364-103.159-218.455-218.455-218.455-121.364 0-218.455 97.091-218.455 218.455z"></path></svg>
    </button>
  </form>
</header>

<ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#">Change Date Format</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Change First Day of the Week</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Change Font Size</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Change Language</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Change Time Format</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: So I tried saving the file as html and it works when I save it in my file system on the computer. However for my website I've been using *Cyberduck*. When I copy the file to Cyberduck the java script part doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any experience with Cyberduck?

Comment: I dont see any PHP code, so I guess the first question would be are you showing us the file that is the PHP File

Comment: A PHP file =is= an HTML file, with possibly some PHP in it. Since you have none there shouldn't be any difference between a PHP file and a HTML file.

Comment: **Doesn't work** Is not a very helpful description

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I just copied this code into a `tst.php` file and it runs perfectly well and the search still works. Not a big surprise really!

Comment: So I am guessing you do not have a web server installed OR it is not configured to include PHP. When you run this file (with the .php extension) Does the address bar say `file:///yourfilename.php` or `http://locahost/tst.php`

Comment: Just thought about that I may need to add a php code part that sends myInput to the server? Maybe I end up having to use mysqli anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly  That was the whole php file I've shown before. It does say http://localhost/myfilename.php I don't know where I would get error messages to be honest. I guess I have to try again using php code. But luckily for that there is already an entry on stackoverflow

Comment: Well as there is not PHP code the most likely place would be the browsers "developers tools" debug area. F12 when the page loads will show you the debugger to see any JS errors or network issues

Comment: CyberDuck is a file browser for remote storage, effectivly a tool to copy files between servers. It doesn't make sense to say "copy the file to CyberDuck".

If not already configured you need to install a web server (for example: Apache, IIS, Nginx). The web server can be configured to run the PHP engine if required. If the web server is installed on a different computer you can use CyberDuck to transfer files to it.

Answer (score 0):

The html is correct. Do the begin tag `<?php` and end tag of php `?>` on the .php file.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
form {
        background-color: #990000;
        width: 300px;
        height: 44px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        align-items:center;
      }

      input {
        all: unset;
        font: 18px system-ui;
        color: #fff;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 6px 10px;
      }

      ::placeholder {
        color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.7; 
      }

      svg {
        color: #fff;
        fill: currentColor;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      button {
        all: unset;
        cursor: pointer;
        width:44px;
        height:44px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<header>
<h2>Search</h2>
<form role="search" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search..." title="Type in a name">
    <button>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><path class="path1" d="M848.471 928l-263.059-263.059c-48.941 36.706-110.118 55.059-177.412 55.059-171.294 0-312-140.706-312-312s140.706-312 312-312c171.294 0 312 140.706 312 312 0 67.294-24.471 128.471-55.059 177.412l263.059 263.059-79.529 79.529zM189.623 408.078c0 121.364 97.091 218.455 218.455 218.455s218.455-97.091 218.455-218.455c0-121.364-103.159-218.455-218.455-218.455-121.364 0-218.455 97.091-218.455 218.455z"></path></svg>
    </button>
  </form>
</header>

<ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#">Change Date Format</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Change First Day of the Week</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Change Font Size</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Change Language</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Change Time Format</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Do the begin and end of php tags on the .php file._ Why, there is no php code?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Code Snippet are presently aimed for HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Stack Overflow has no features for executing live demos of PHP code. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Right, but as there are NO php statements in this code .... there is absolutely NO difference between storing this code in a `.html` or a `.php` file :) Which is what the question appears to be about !

Comment: @RiggsFolly no PHP on snippet nor php tags on code block from question. I added something to view and could miss. Hope it helps someone.